# How to integrate Koa, Passport and MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, passport.js, koa, koa-passport

***Please don't ignore the question looking at its length. It might seem long because I've attached the code. The actual problem statement is really small.**

I've tried integrating **Passport,** **Koa &** **MongoDB** from the last two days. I've been failing and am unable to get any references regarding the problem I've been facing. My primary concern is to just get the login module working.

**My problem** is that the function to handle post request for login in my index routes, associated with koa-passport is being called and ctx.body is also being sent as a response but successRedirect and failureRedirect aren't working. Down below are the files that I'm using.

In the **auth.js**, I have console logged user inside the new LocalStrategy, right after **var user =** line. Nothing is logged to the console.

**auth.js**

```
const passport = require('koa-passport')
const LocalStretegy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const User =  mongoose.model('User', mongoose.Schema({}, { strict: false }))

function *getUser(name) {
  let user = yield User.find({username: name})
  return user
}

passport.serializeUser( (user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id)
})

passport.deserializeUser( async (id, done) => {
  done(null, user)
})

passport.use(new LocalStretegy( (username, password, done) => {
  co(function*() {
    try {
      var user = yield getUser(username)
      if (user.username === username && user.password === password) {
        return user
      } else {
        return null
      }
    } catch(e) {
      return null
    }
  }).then((user) => {
    done(null, user)
  })
}))

module.exports = passport
```

**/routes/index.js**

```
const router = require('koa-router')()
const sendfile = require('koa-sendfile')
const passport = require('koa-passport')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Counter = mongoose.model('Counter', mongoose.Schema({}, { strict: false }))

router.post('/custom', (ctx, next) => {
  return passport.authenticate('local', function(user, info, status) {
    if (user === false) {
      ctx.status = 401
      ctx.body = { success: false }
      ctx.body = { success: true }
    } else {
      return ctx.login(user)
    }
  })(ctx, next)
})

router.post('/login', (ctx) => {
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/dash-board',
    failureRedirect: '/login'
  })
  ctx.body={status: 'okay'}
})

router.get('/logout', (ctx) => {
  ctx.logout()
  ctx.redirect('/')
})

module.exports = router
```

**app.js**

```
const Koa = require('koa')
const router = require('koa-router')()
const app = new Koa()

app.proxy = true

//Routes
const users = require('./routes/users')
const index = require('./routes/index')

//Error handler
const onerror = require('koa-onerror')
onerror(app)

//MongoDB connection
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
try{
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://<user>:<pass>@<something>.mlab.com:<number>/<someDB>?poolSize=10&retries=5')
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err)
}

// Sessions
const convert = require('koa-convert')
const session = require('koa-generic-session')
const MongoStore = require('koa-generic-session-mongo')
app.keys = ['key1']
app.use(convert(session({
  store: new MongoStore()
})))

//body parser
const bodyparser = require('koa-bodyparser')
app.use(bodyparser({
  enableTypes:['json', 'form', 'text']
}))

//passport
require('./auth')
const passport = require('koa-passport')
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

app.use(index.routes(), index.allowedMethods(),                                     users.prefix('/index'))

app.use((ctx, next) => {
  if(ctx.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next()
  } else {
    ctx.redirect('/')
  }
})

app.use((ctx, next) => {
  return next().catch(function (err) {
    ctx.status = err.status || 500;
    if (err.expose) {
      ctx.body = err.message;
    }
  })
})

module.exports = app
```

I am unable to deduce anything from here on. I've searched extensively and changed the code to work until here.

Comment: Well `yield User.find({username: name})` **definitely** should be `yield User.findOne({username: name})`, because `.find()` returns a `Cursor`, where you are clearly expecting a "plain object". Frankly you're probably going overboard with generators and should simply return the promise and resolve that. At a glace you have a few problems that would be better approached by "breaking it into the smaller parts" and then understanding what each bit actually does. For example, understanding Promises and Generators is probably a good place to start. Then understand each API.

Comment: `User.findOne({ username: username, password: password }, done)
    .then((user) => {
      console.log(user);
      if(!user) { return null }
      else { return user }
      return done(null, user)
    })` Is this what you're suggesting me for going overboard with generators?

Comment: I think this might be helpful http://mherman.org/blog/2018/01/02/user-authentication-with-passport-and-koa/#.Ws8vbdNuaAw

Comment: @RajThakarI've already implemented that. it is of no use. I have been getting the same problem (nothing related to login logic works, successRedirect & faiureRedirect don't work) again and again.

Comment: I recommend you to give up generators and to adopt js promises instead. Koa was designed for them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has something to do with this code in which `user` does not seem to be declared.

```
passport.deserializeUser( async (id, done) => {
  done(null, user)
})
```